# How to parse a structured file in c# with ArrayList?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have a text file like this.
[image]

I convert it into a structured format like below.

```
public static ArrayList ConllToStructured(string filepath)
    {
        ArrayList structuredfile = new ArrayList();
        string currentline;
        int currentsentence = 0;
        //Read conll file and Convert it to a structured Array list
        //First column is sentence number and other 12 columns is conll fileds

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != "#end document")
            {
                if (currentline.Contains("#begin document")) continue;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentline))
                {
                    currentsentence += 1;
                    continue;
                }

                //parse each line with whitespace and save in array
                var words = currentline.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                //Save sentence number and word array into a temp array list
                List<string> templine = new List<string>();
                templine.Add(currentsentence.ToString());
                foreach (var columns in words)
                {
                    templine.Add(columns);
                }


                structuredfile.Add(templine);
            }
        }
        return structuredfile;
    }
```

But, when I want to access this structured file, I can only access to each row but I can't access each column in rows. I add arrays of string to ArrayList for further access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood what you are asking in your question is how from the returned `ArrayList` you can get given column for given row.

I think it would be a better option to return from this method `List<List<string>>`. Then later when you want to access specific column in a specific row. You can just do

```
var structuredFile = ConllToStructured(filepath);
var columnString = structuredFile[rowIndex][colIndex];
```

But if for some reason you need it to be `ArrayList` you should know that `ArrayList` is always from objects. So when you access an element from it you will be returned object, which you need to cast to `List<string>` so you would do something like this:

```
var columnString = (structuredFile[rowIndex] as List<string>)[colIndex];
```